# Server architecture for a scalable Facebook game

Tags: .net, facebook, caching, scalability, cluster-computing

Some friends and I have written a game for Facebook without much thought into the actual architecture of the game - and imagine our surprise when we reached over 300,000 unique players per month and as our servers melted down.

Now we're working on redesigning the entire server side of the game in order to make it much more scalable and able to support hundreds of thousands if not millions of users.

Currently I'm new to the entire scaling concept, but from what I understood more or less this is what we need:
1. A load balancer
2. A web server per 20,000~ concurrent users (We've contacted a 3rd party Comet developer that claims they can support up to 20,000 concurrent connections per node)
3. A caching cluster
4. Database cluster

Now this is all very abstract obviously, but am I missing anything?
If we are developing this in .NET, can anyone recommend a good cluster cache server technology?

Keep in mind that:

1. We aim to reach millions of players
2. We aim to reach 10s/100s of thousands of concurrent users
3. We need to keep as much as possible data on cache and dump it into the DB every period of time
4. We do have some sort of interactions between players (Get player score updates, etc) and we need a centralized or replicated cache to work on (basically meaning that we need the cache data that all web servers access to be completely synched)

Answer (score 1):

What about deploying it into the Azure cloud? Believing what they say, scalability will be no more your concern.

Instead of creating a DB cluster, what about splitting players to different "servers", "worlds" or however you might call it in your game. I don't know what type of game you'r talking about, but most browser games I play do this to be able to handle the load.

Comment: OK that's an option however, does the Azure cloud allow us to use the following?
* Database clusters
* Cache clusters

Also, keep in mind that we aim for 100,000s/1,000,000s of concurrent users, and some actions require immediate and synchronized information on different players.

Comment: Azure handles load balancing for you, so adding more instances under a role will automatically route players to different instances (servers). What are you using for a database? There are many different options for handling this in azure as well.